Criterion for products of projections.
Given an arbitrary vector space $V$ and two (linear) projections $P$ and $Q$.
In the case of orthogonal projections, it is relatively easy to show that the product $PQ$ is a projection if and only if $P$ and $Q$ commute. This yields $\mathcal N(PQ)=\mathcal N(P)+\mathcal N(Q)$ and $\mathcal R(PQ)=\mathcal R(P)\cap \mathcal R(Q)$.
For arbitrary (linear) projections, it is relatively easy to find a counterexample that $P$ and $Q$ do not have to commute, but $PQ$ is a projection.
Now my Question: Is there nevertheless a suitable criterion here?

A example is given by P(x,y)=(x,x) and Q(x,y)=(x,0) for real x. We have P^2=P and Q^2=Q, but PQ=P≠Q=QP
